# How to make this content loop inside divs

Tags: php

I got this code to generate a list of 6 random products.
How can I make it generate each product inside a div?

```
$max_items = 6;
for($i = 0; $i < $max_items; $i++) {
    echo  $ps_product->show_snapshot($prodlist[$rand_prods[$i]], $show_price, $show_addtocart);
}
```

Comment: You can just put it between div tags?! Where exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$max_items = 6;

for($i = 0; $i < $max_items; $i++) {
   echo '<div>' . $ps_product->show_snapshot($prodlist[$rand_prods[$i]], $show_price, $show_addtocart) . '</div>';
}
```

Comment: this makes the first item inside a div, and the second item inside the first div, and so on... very weird!

Answer (score 0):

```
$max_items = 6;

for($i = 0; $i < $max_items; $i++) {
   printf('<div> %s </div>',$ps_product->show_snapshot($prodlist[$rand_prods[$i]], $show_price, $show_addtocart));
}
```